# What exactly does it mean for a measure to be translation-invariant?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,A,\mu)$ be a measure space.

What does it mean exactly if $\mu$ is translation invariant?

Let $T\colon X\to X$ be a translation. Then
$$
\mu(A')=\mu(T(A'))?
$$
for $A'\in A$?

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is a measure space and $T : X \rightarrow X$ is a measurable mapping, we say that $\mu$ is $T-$invariant if $\mu(T^{-1}(A)) = \mu(A)$ for all $A \in \mathcal{A}$.

If $X$ has a group structure with binary operation $+$ then for each $y \in X$ we can define a map $T_y : X \rightarrow X$ by 
$$T_y(x) = x + y, \quad x \in X.$$

To say that $\mu$ is translation invariant is to say that $\mu$ is is $T_y$-invariant  for all $y \in X$.

Fact: Any compact Lie group admits a (unique up to scaling) translation invariant measure, called a Haar measure. For instance, on $S^1$ Lebesgue measure is a Haar measure. The hypotheses of this result can be significantly weakened. However, there is no Haar measure on an infinite dimensional space like $C([0,1],\|\cdot\|_\infty)$.